# how to custom set prototype chaining(constructor)?

Tags: javascript

Im studing javascript chaining but i cant set constructor deep as i want.

```
function a() {}
function b() {}
function c() {}

a.prototype.text1 = 'text1';
b.prototype.text2 = 'text2';
c.prototype.text3 = 'text3';

a.prototype.constructor = b;
b.prototype.constructor = c;

var foo = new a();

console.log(foo.text1) // it`s output 'text1'. yea~ it`s right!
// But...
console.log(foo.text3) // it`s output undefined. My intention was output 'test3'.
```

Why is this happening?
What can I do?

please help. thanks.

Comment: A recommendation on OLOO design instead: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create).

```js
function a() {}
function b() {}
function c() {}

c.prototype.text3 = 'text3';

b.prototype = Object.create(c.prototype);
b.prototype.text2 = 'text2';

a.prototype = Object.create(b.prototype);
a.prototype.text1 = 'text1';

var foo = new a();

console.log(foo.text1);
console.log(foo.text2);
console.log(foo.text3);
```

`Object.create()` basically creates an object with its prototype into another object's prototype.

Doing something like `a.prototype.constructor = b` is merely setting `constructor` property to `b`, not adding prototype of `b` to `a` at all.

If you understand ES6 syntax, this is easier to understand (although the result is technically not the same):

```js
class C {
  constructor(){
    this.text3 = 'text3';
  }
}

class B extends C {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.text2 = 'text2';
  }
}

class A extends B {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.text1 = 'text1';
  }
}

var foo = new A();

console.log(foo.text1);
console.log(foo.text2);
console.log(foo.text3);
```

<s>**EDIT**</s>

[`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) is the more appropriate way to do it.

```js
function a() {}
function b() {}
function c() {}

c.prototype.text3 = 'text3';

b.prototype = Object.assign(c.prototype);
b.prototype.text2 = 'text2';

a.prototype = Object.assign(b.prototype);
a.prototype.text1 = 'text1';

var foo = new a();

console.log(foo.text1);
console.log(foo.text2);
console.log(foo.text3);
```

Comment: @msm082919 check out the ES6 syntax that I just updated. It's easier to understand if you know ES6.

Comment: i think the last way is wrong. i can read property text3 when  `var foo = new b()`

Comment: @msm082919 isn't that what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to explore [Behaviour Delegation](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md), and ditch all the ugly prototype boilerplate. An example to achieve your objective as below:

```js
let obj1 = {
  text1: 'Text 1'
}
let obj2 = Object.create(obj1)
obj2.text2 =  'Text 2';
let obj3 = Object.create(obj2)
obj3.text3 =  'Text 3';

let foo = obj3;
console.log(foo.text1)//Text 1
console.log(foo.text2)//Text 2
console.log(foo.text3)//Text 3
```

The above code is known as OLOO style (Object Linked To Another Object) instead of Prototype style

Here is another [link](https://gist.github.com/getify/5572383) to show you both the code side by side for comparison

Comment: This is great advice for scenarios where only single objects are expected to be used. However, `class`es do have the benefit of templating construction for an arbitrary amount of instances, so keep in mind this is not ideal in all situations. +1